# How do I tidy up my data set when my variables for time are "FY2017Q1", FY2017Q2", etc?

Tags: r, tidyr

My data set below is in wide format and I'd like to transform it to long format. I'd like the columns to be "Year" and "Quarter" instead of how it is below. My first thought was to use spread() then gather() but I'm not sure how to go about doing that with the way my data is set up. Typically, this data is analyzed in Excel using pivot tables and is set up this way to limit number of rows used.

```
# A tibble: 957,545 x 3
   FY2017Q1 FY2017Q2 FY2017Q3
      <int>    <int>    <int>
 1      149       NA       NA
 2       22       NA       NA
 3       NA       NA      268
 4       NA       NA       NA
 5        1       NA       NA
 6       49       NA       NA
 7       NA       NA       NA
 8       NA       NA       NA
 9       NA      225      300
10       NA      196      167
# ... with 957,535 more rows
```

Comment: can you provide more information about what are you actually loading in R?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your variable names are all nicely formatted as "FY####Q#", the following should do the job:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(key, value) %>%
  mutate(Year = substring(key, 3, 6),
         Quarter = substring(key, 7, 8)) %>%
  select(Year, Quarter, value) %>%
  na.omit() # skip this step if you want to keep the NAs

   Year Quarter value
1  2017      Q1   149
2  2017      Q1    22
5  2017      Q1     1
6  2017      Q1    49
19 2017      Q2   225
20 2017      Q2   196
23 2017      Q3   268
29 2017      Q3   300
30 2017      Q3   167
```

Sample data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "   FY2017Q1 FY2017Q2 FY2017Q3
                      1      149       NA       NA
                      2       22       NA       NA
                      3       NA       NA      268
                      4       NA       NA       NA
                      5        1       NA       NA
                      6       49       NA       NA
                      7       NA       NA       NA
                      8       NA       NA       NA
                      9       NA      225      300
                      10       NA      196      167")
> df
   FY2017Q1 FY2017Q2 FY2017Q3
1       149       NA       NA
2        22       NA       NA
3        NA       NA      268
4        NA       NA       NA
5         1       NA       NA
6        49       NA       NA
7        NA       NA       NA
8        NA       NA       NA
9        NA      225      300
10       NA      196      167
```